# How to add a button in ActiveAdmin to create a new record for another resource, with fields pre-populated with values from the current resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

In my ActiveAdmin dashboard, I have two resources - Posts and ScrapedPosts. For a ScrapedPost, I want to add a *Publish Post* button, which, when clicked, goes to a page for creating a new Post (*new* action), where all the fields for *Post* are pre-filled with values from ScrapedPost (Post and ScrapedPost have identical schema).

Here is my current code inside *app/admin/scraped_post.rb*

```
ActiveAdmin.register ScrapedPost do

  action_item :view, only: :show do
    link_to "Publish Post", new_admin_post_path
  end

end
```

This adds a new button called *Publish Post*. When I click on it, as expected, it creates a page for adding a new *Post*. However, I want the fields pre-filled with the values from the current ScrapedPost from where I am creating the post.

I have tried a number of things so far. The documentation for *action_item* is very basic and it didn't help. [It looks like I can't pass parameters to the action identified by *new_admin_post_path*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287089/how-to-call-a-method-and-send-new-parameters-in-ror). How can I do it?

[I started learning RoR just this week, so I'll be grateful if you can explain your solution as well.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `action_item` is doing is injecting a link styled as a button onto the show page. You can pass parameters to the link target by embedding them in the link. However, `new` does not accept parameters so to copy a Post what you need is a `member_action`:

```
member_action :clone do
  resource.clone
  render :new
end
```

This action can be invoked so:

```
action_item :clone, only: :show do
  link_to "Publish Post", clone_admin_post_path
end
```

Make sure first that works for copying a Post. If you want to create a ScrapedPost from a Post then you will need to pass the id of the Post as a parameter:

```
link_to "Publish Post", clone_admin_scraped_post_path(post_id: resource.id)
```

then the ScrapedPost member action can find it:

```
member_action :clone do
  @scraped_post = Post.find(params[:post_id]).clone.becomes(ScrapedPost)
  render :new
end
```

As an aside, for better or worse ActiveAdmin is an additional layer of abstraction on top of Ruby on Rails so my recommendation is always to master vanilla Rails first to ease the learning curve.